# Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings. (After migrating WAMP setup to another server)

Tags: php, database, wamp, wampserver

So I tried to move a WAMP setup from one server to another but after, when I tried localhost I got a Database error message:

[Database error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCPby.png)

When I go the files stated in the message I don't see what could be wrong.

**DB_driver.php**

```
// Connect to the database and set the connection ID
    $this->conn_id = ($this->pconnect == FALSE) ? $this->db_connect() : $this->db_pconnect();

    // No connection resource?  Throw an error
    if ( ! $this->conn_id)
    {
        log_message('error', 'Unable to connect to the database');

        if ($this->db_debug)
        {
            $this->display_error('db_unable_to_connect');
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
```

**mysqli_driver.php**

```
/**
 * Non-persistent database connection
 *
 * @access  private called by the base class
 * @return  resource
 */
function db_connect()
{
    if ($this->port != '')
    {
        return @mysqli_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database, $this->port);
    }
    else
    {
        return @mysqli_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);
    }

}
```

Now I'm not very skilled when it comes to PHP and such, not at all in fact.

Comment: Make sure your connection information is valid

Comment: Your connection settings are incorrect. Please check the same.

Comment: If the code worked before then most likely the issue is not the code, is it? It probably is the connection details you configured. Or that no such database service exists at all...

Comment: Please do not put any text (including code, error messages and your question) in images.